# Recarregar form.custom.inpval após salvar form

Tags: python, web2py

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em web2py e tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Fiz um custom form que possui um campo que envia uma imagem com preview. O código é assim:

```
{{=data['form'].custom.begin}}

    {{dsp = data['form'].custom.dspval}}
    {{inp = data['form'].custom.inpval}}
    {{lbl = data['form'].custom.label}}
    {{wid = data['form'].custom.widget}}

    .
    .
    .
    {{=B(lbl.logo)}}
    {{=wid.logo}}
    {{if inp.logo != '':}}
        <br /><img src="{{=URL('static', 'upload/empresa/logo/'+inp.logo)}}" width="120" />
    {{pass}}
    .
    .
    .

{{=data['form'].custom.end}}
```

O db.py é assim:

```
.
.
Field('logo',
    label='Logo',
    type="upload",
    uploadfolder=os.path.join(request.folder,'static/upload/empresa/logo'),
    autodelete=True
),
.
.
```

Quando processo o form, o web2py não atualiza o valor do `inp.logo`, apenas quando dou reload na view.

O `wid.logo` traz o input, então não serve como preview da imagem. Como devo fazer para recarregar o `inp.logo`?

Comment: Apenas para entender melhor: você quer que o usuário clique no campo de envio de imagem, escolha a imagem, e ela apareça imediatamente, sem ter que dar refresh na página?

Answer (score 0):

Para recarregar o valor de `inp.logo` após o envio do formulário no web2py, você pode usar o método `update_record()` do formulário para atualizar o registro no banco de dados e, em seguida, recarregar a página para atualizar os valores de `dsp` e `inp`.

A primeira etapa é processar o formulário como de costume, usando o método `process()` do formulário:

```
form.process()
```

Isso validará os campos do formulário e, se não houver erros, salvará os dados no banco de dados.

Em seguida, você pode usar o método `update_record()` do formulário para atualizar o registro no banco de dados e recarregar a página:

```
form.update_record()
redirect(URL(args=request.args, vars=request.vars))
```

Isso fará com que o web2py atualize o registro no banco de dados e recarregue a página com os novos valores de `dsp` e `inp`.

Observe que você também pode usar o método `update_record()` para atualizar apenas alguns campos do formulário, passando os valores desejados como argumentos para o método. Por exemplo, para atualizar apenas o campo logo, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
form.update_record(logo=form.vars.logo)
redirect(URL(args=request.args, vars=request.vars))
```

Espero que isso ajude! Qualquer dúvida, estou à disposição.